# progress bar when uploading images with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to display a progress bar when I am uploading images when it does not work. Could you explain me why ? I may have missed something.

This is the code in the XHTML file

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="true" update="messages" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" onstart="PF('pbAjax').start()"/>  

 <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{progressBean.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}% #{progressBean.workToDo}" styleClass="animated" >
   <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{controleBean.onComplete}" update="messages" oncomplete="startButton2.enable()"/>                            
</p:progressBar>
```

And

```
 @ManagedBean(name="fileUploadController", eager = true)
 @SessionScoped
 public class FileUploadController {

 @ManagedProperty(  value= "#{progressBean}")
 private ProgressBean progressBean;

 private boolean onComplete;

 public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  

   System.out.println("Job starts...");
   onComplete=false;
   getProgressBean().setProgress(0);
   getProgressBean().setWorkToDo("Import launch");

   ... do some stuff

   getProgressBean().setWorkToDo("Import finished");
   onComplete=true;


}
```

And

```
@ManagedBean(name = "progressBean",eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class ProgressBean implements Serializable{

   private String workToDo;
   private Integer progress;

}
```

Comment: There is already a progress bar associated with each file you upload using `<p:fileUpload>`, when `mode` is set to `advanced`. Why do you then need a separate progress bar, `<p:progressBar>`?

Comment: well, the an ideal case, I would like to have both a download bar for each file and a global downaload bar for all the files selected, it don't know it is possible